# Name look-up of local machines fails when using different OS

Tags: windows-7, linux, networking, dns

This works

- Look-up through ip address
- Look-up the ip of a GNU/Linux machine from another GNU/Linux machine
- Look-up the ip of a Windows XP machine from a Windows 7 machine
- Look-up the router ip from any machine

This does not work:

- Look-up from Windows to GNU/Linux or vice versa
- nslookup in any case

Info about the router (D-LINK):

```
Model Name: DIR-859
Hardware Version: A3
Firmware Version: 1.04
```

I have tried nslookup, which fails. This is what I get on the linux prompt (darkmatter is also running linux so this should work):

```
 nslookup darkmatter.local
 Server:         127.0.1.1
 Address:        127.0.1.1#53

** server can't find darkmatter.local: NXDOMAIN
```

But

```
PING darkmatter.local (192.168.0.45) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.45: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.626 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.45: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.728 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.45: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.498 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.45: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.483 ms
^C
--- darkmatter.local ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.483/0.583/0.728/0.104 ms
```

If I try darkmatter from the Windows 7 box (dns suffix local):

```
ping darkmatter
Ping-begäran kunde inte hitta värddator darkmatter. Kontrollera namnet och prova igen.
```

However:

```
ping 192.168.0.45
Skickar ping-signal till 192.168.0.45 med 32 byte data:
Svar från 192.168.0.45: byte=32 tid=1ms TTL=64
Svar från 192.168.0.45: byte=32 tid < 1 ms TTL=64
Svar från 192.168.0.45: byte=32 tid < 1 ms TTL=64
Svar från 192.168.0.45: byte=32 tid < 1 ms TTL=64

Ping-statistik för 192.168.0.45:
    Paket: Skickade = 4, Mottagna = 4, Förlorade = 0 (0 %),
Ungefärlig överföringstid i millisekunder:
    Lägsta = 0 ms, Högsta = 1 ms, Medel = 0 ms
```

The problem appeared after switching router.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because unlike most other OSes, Windows doesn't support the IETF ZeroConf mDNS RFCs for the .local domain. Instead, Microsoft chose to create a proprietary thing called LLMNR and use .local for that thing.

When a desktop Linux box uses .local, it is often using Avahi, which is an open source implementation of the IETF's ZeroConf RFCs. Android Linux devices use the POSIX portable, open source, mDNSResponder daemon that Apple originated (Bonjour is just Apple's branding for IETF ZeroConf mDNS).

Apple products also use mDNSResponder.

Apple maintains an mDNSResponder port for Windows, called Bonjour for Windows. Installing that is probably the easiest way to get standard IETF ZeroConf mDNS support working on Windows so it can properly interoperate with your Linux, Android, and Apple devices.

Comment: What happened to NetBIOS